# Computational time of well-known compression algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I have googled for get information about computational time of some compression algorithms but information seems contradict each other. I need worst case performance of the following algorithm Sliding Window, Open Window, Threshold and STTrace. 
All algorithms [should have quadratic time](http://bit.ly/JPkPbk). Do you confirm?

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with GIS. You might have better luck asking this on http://stackoverflow.com.